# Fill a div with numbers from 1 to 870

Tags: javascript

I'm quite a newbie at Javascript and I'm sure this is an easy one.

I'm almost there, the only thing is that I want a space between each number and I want them to break at the end of the div, weirdly it doesn't happen and it appears a comma that I really do not want.

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++) {
points[i] = i + 1; }

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
$(".numbers").html((points) + " ")}
```

```css
.number{width:100vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=numbers></div>
```

Comment: `.number{width:100vw}` this does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the array elements with a space between them :

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++) {
points[i] = i + 1; }


$(".numbers").html(points.join(' '))
```

```css
.number{width:100vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=numbers></div>
```

Comment: So where did those comma's come from?

Comment: @usr2564301 i don't see any commas .. ( Firefox 61, Chrome 67 ) , ah ! you mean in the question .. it's due to automatic conversion of the array to a string ( because of this `points + " "` )

Answer (score 0):

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 0; i < 870; i++) {
 points[i] = i + 1; 
}

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
 $(".numbers").append("<div>"+points[i]+"</div>");
}
```

```css
.number{width:100vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=numbers></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)... without jQuery and `for`ing over precise values.

```js
var points = new Array(870);
for (var i = 1; i <= 870; i++) {
  points[i] = i;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("numbers")[0].innerText = points.join(' ');
```

```html
<div class=numbers></div>
```